# Confused About the K-MAP Minimization

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map

I want to Construct a priority encoder which implements the encoding of 0,3,1,2
with descending priority (i.e. 0 has the highest priority and 2 has the
lowest.
**but i am confused about my KMAP I am getting same Equation for both Y_1 and Y_2 . Moreover i am getting I_0 term common in both equation .**

[image]

Comment: Why do you not embrace actives low?  None of your answers are correct.  And you have no active low terms.

Comment: You are being careless in filling the 1s I see. Try once more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your initial table implies what I think it does, then I completely agree with your k-maps:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Y_1&\overline{I_1}\:\overline{I_0}&\overline{I_1}\: I_0&I_1 \:I_0&I_1 \:\overline{I_0}\\
\hline
\overline{I_3}\:\overline{I_2}&x&0&0&0\\
\overline{I_3}\:I_2 &1&0&0&0\\
I_3\: I_2 &1&0&0&1\\
I_3\:\overline{I_2} &1&0&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Y_2&\overline{I_1}\:\overline{I_0}&\overline{I_1}\: I_0&I_1 \:I_0&I_1 \:\overline{I_0}\\
\hline
\overline{I_3}\:\overline{I_2}&x&0&0&1\\
\overline{I_3}\:I_2&0&0&0&1\\
I_3\: I_2&1&0&0&1\\
I_3\:\overline{I_2}&1&0&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

I also agree with your circled areas:

.....................[image]

The green area for \$Y_1\$ is \$\overline{I_1}\:\overline{I_0}\$ and the orange area for \$Y_1\$ is \$I_3\:\overline{I_0}\$. So \$Y_1=\overline{I_1}\:\overline{I_0}+I_3\:\overline{I_0}\$.

The green area for \$Y_2\$ is \$I_1\:\overline{I_0}\$ and the orange area for \$Y_2\$ is \$I_3\:\overline{I_0}\$. So \$Y_2=I_1\:\overline{I_0}+I_3\:\overline{I_0}\$.

These are not the same.

I think you did very well, except that you missed just one small detail about the condition of \$I_1\$ between the two k-maps. That's all.